# Diaries or writings of Cathar Perfecti in 12th Century France

Tags: middle-ages, religion, france, inquisition

The Cathars were a Gnostic sect of southern (Languedoc) France in the 12th Century. "Perfecti" were individuals in the sect who followed the most extremely austere lives, renouncing worldly pleasures including eating of meat and sex.  Did any diaries or writings from these Perfecti survive to modern times?

Answer (score 3):

See *Textes pour les cahiers du sud* (1987) and *Ecritures cathares* (1968) by Rene Nelli.

The most famous tract is the *The Provencal Ritual of the Albigeois* published in facsimile by [Jean Cledat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Cl%C3%A9dat):

[image]